# ScriptManager has no IsNavigating property

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to follow instructions from [this video](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-242.aspx) and add Back/Forward button support to a wizard (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard`). However, the `ScriptManager` object in my code has no `IsNavigating` property.

Why?
What do I have to install? (I have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed)
What version of `System.Web.Extensions` should I see in GAC? (I have 3.5.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you select the framework as 3.5 when you created the project?

Edit: It seems your project was developed using .net framework 2.0. This is the reason why you had to convert the project to VS 2008.

Comment: Right click the project and click -> Property Pages . In the resulting Window, Click Build Tab and you can see the framework there. Since Its old project I think it should be using 2.0 ...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2005 and maybe that's why I cannot see the information about the framework - http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/2213/pp1.png and http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7421/pp2u.png

Comment: I am using VS 2008.. Dont have VS 2005 now.. Will be able to post tomorrow from office.

Comment: I converted the project to VS 2008. After conversion, I checked selected version of .NET framework - it was set to 3.5; maybe the conversion project changed it automatically. I'm not sure; however, this solved the problem.